# need a better way to go back to main.py from another module such as 'setting.py' avoiding the circular import issue

Tags: python, debugging

i have a terminal program, and there is a function in main.py 'cmd()' this is the main terminal, where the commands are and where my other module, setting.py, needs to go back to when i type in the exit command for setting.py

as the title indicates, i can't do this due to circular importing, and i do not intend to merge this all into main.py as it's highly unorganized.

this is essentially how im importing the module functions

main.py:

```
import setting

setting.settingFunction()
```

setting.py

```
import main

main.cmd()
```

the main.cmd() in setting.py occurs when you type in the exit command, intending to send you back to the main terminal, main.py. for main.py, when you type in 'settings', it sends to the settingFunction() with customizable setting
commands for the terminal.

here is an image example of what i'm trying to do. the top part is the main.py, and when i type in 'settings' it goes to setting.py's settingFunction()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uG8x.png)

attempt one:

i've attempted renaming the modules, yet it still gives the circular import error.

attempt two:

i've attempted making a sort of 'common.py' module to import back and forth with the same result of circular import error

attempt three:

i've attempted placing the imports at the very end of the modules, this time it didn't work (as like the last two attempts)

attempt four:

placing the imports in the spots that it needs to run at, the result still doesn't work, as it works in the vscode terminal, yet not as a standalone application through python

attempt five:

using importlib inside of the spot that it is ran in, and outside of it, with the first importlib placement resulting in the result of attempt four and the second importlib placement resulting in the same circular import error

i don't know any other way to make it work with eachother without the circular import error, and it has to be this way for my terminal to work.

Comment: (1) Show textual information as properly formatted text (here: as code) in the question, not as comment, image or external link. (2) Going back this way produces a recursion which, if the program runs long enough and is used often enough, leads to a crash. Better wrap functionality of the commands in functions which `return` to `main` on exit.

Comment: thank you, but how do i make it return to main?

Comment: A `return` in `settingFunction` at the appropriate place and a loop (usually `while True:`) in `main.cmd` in which the next command is asked from the user and then processed. If you have difficulties, show the code properly formatted in the question.

Comment: thank you! i've been struggling with this issue for a while now and it's been a pain. tysm